# How to write a jQuery selector with multiple :eq's in single expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a quick question. How do I write a jQuery selector expression with multiple :eq() selectors? I want to go down the DOM tree but every hope isn't uniform. Here is what I have that works:

```
$('div:eq(0)').find('div:eq(1)').find('div:eq(5)')
```

But is the following does not work:

```
$('div:eq(0) div:eq(1) div:eq(5)')
```

Is there a more elegant way to write it without all the "find"'s?

Comment: Is there a typo in the first line?  Should it have a class selector before the `eq(0)`?

Comment: You are correct, this is a typo..fixed.

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/s3scr/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe that you could do the following and it should return all dom elements that match:

```
 $('div:eq(0), div:eq(1), div:eq(5)')
```

You could then iterate over the results returned, hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you can't use multiple index inside the :eq selector. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 23):

Using an [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop - elegant and not repetitive:

```
$.each([0, 1, 5], (_, n) => {
    $('div').eq(n);
});
```

Last I checked, this technique performs best:

```
$('div').filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(5)');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your indexes are in an array and you're planning to chain methods on your collection :

```
var aIndexes = [1,6,17];
$collection.filter( function() {
   return aIndexes.indexOf($(this).index()) > -1;
} ).<chained methods on filtered collection>
```