# How select element by position ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several Divs class Arc, how do I select and set an attribute using the position as a reference?

for example:

```
$(".FirstClass .Arc").css("background-color",color);
$(".ThirdClass .Arc").css("background-color",color);
$(".FourthClass .Arc").css("background-color",color);

<div class="get">
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Secretaria</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#f6c201" />

        </div>

        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Financeiro</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#97BE0D" />


        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Acadêmico</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#C5EF63" />

        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Biblioteca</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#88B8E6" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Portaria</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#BEDBE9" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Aluno</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#B02E98" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Responsável</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#ED3237" />
        </div>
        <div class="arc">
            <span class="text">Professor</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="percent" value="100" />
            <input type="hidden" class="color" value="#F58634" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use the .each(function(i)){} to find a attribute, but i Want set a attribute to all .Arc class element, and I want to set a different attribute for a specific element using the position reference

Comment: if you just want to select one div by position you can use `.arc:eq(index)` to get the one at the specified index

Comment: Or you could use `$('.arc').eq(index)`. Koala's way, `$('.arc:eq(index)')`, is faster though. Keep in mind 0 would be the first position. If you want multiple to be selected you can [do it this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449449/how-to-write-a-jquery-selector-with-multiple-eqs-in-single-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery eq()
for example

`$('.arc:eq(0)').css();`

`$('.arc:eq(1)').css();`

or use like this

`$('.arc').eq(0).css();`

`$('.arc').eq(1).css();`

Comment: If the answer is provided in the comments by another user it is generally practiced to not provide the same answer in an Answer unless the OP asks for the user to

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do `$(".arc:nth-child( index )")` 
to select an element

If my syntax is correct, you should be able to do this:

`$(".arc:nth-child(4)").css("background-color",'yellow');`

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/mnjCQ/2)**

Answer (score 0):

What about a loop using each, but referencing various predefined classes (.co0, .co1, .co2  ...):

```
$('div.arc').each(function(i){ $(this).addClass('co'+(i%6)); });
```

The classes are something like

```
.co0 {background-color:#ebc}
.co1 {background-color:#fcc}
.co2 {background-color:#ffc}
.co3 {background-color:#dfe}
.co4 {background-color:#cff}
.co5 {background-color:#ccf}
```

The loop variable `i` refers to the position. I used the `i%6` simply because I was too lazy to define 8 different colors ...

Comment: I was studying more about the possibilities of "FOR" and was looking for how to do this LOL
Thank you, I get it I'll learn a lot here in the community.