# eq with multiple entries filter behaviour

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
function blinkIn() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").eq(1).trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").eq(3).css("stroke", "#FFEB3B");
    blinkOut();
  }, 3000);
}

function blinkOut() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").eq(1).trigger('mouseout.mapify');
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").eq(1).css("stroke", "");
    blinkIn();
  }, 2000);
}

blinkIn();
```

From all the `eq` questions that I found this seems to be the one most similar to my question:

[How to write a jQuery selector with multiple :eq's in single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449449/how-to-write-a-jquery-selector-with-multiple-eqs-in-single-expression)

I understand that using an array is not the best approach speed-wise so I tried using `filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)')`

My new code looks like this:

```
function blinkIn() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').css("stroke", "#FFEB3B");
    blinkOut();
  }, 3000);
}

function blinkOut() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').trigger('mouseout.mapify');
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').css("stroke", "");
    blinkIn();
  }, 2000);
}

blinkIn();
```

It seems to work but it no longer has the same effect that it used to have when I was calling a single `eq`. It used to have an opacity for the stroke that is not applied anymore.

You can check the end result here: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/index.html (the three blinking statues to the left).

I'm using mapify https://github.com/etienne-martin/Mapify to apply highlighting to the image map areas.

My guess is that it has something to do with that `filter`. What does `filter` actually do and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What behavior are you wanting....have them blink in/out in sequence one after the other?

Comment: I want them blinking the same way the do now, only that before I added the filter they had 0.7 opacity so those lines wouldn't look so rough. For some reason if I leave the code as it was before it takes that opacity into account, after I use the filter it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have any link so we can see the original code with 0.7 opacity?

Comment: @EhsanT I posted the original code in the question (in the first part). You can see what result it had by hovering over the statues or the doors. It should look the same after runing this function. Thanks!

Comment: It's weird, the third statue has the opacity but the first and second one do not have. The reason is that the third statue will have a class named `mapify-hover` during `blinkIn()` but the first and second one do not have this class!

Comment: Yeah, don't know why that happens. Do you think it has something to do with that filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many ways on your code, but it seems that in this line:

```
$("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
```

The plugin only applies correctly on the last element in your list no matter what.

I tried to add a specific class like`class="test-mapify"` to the `area` elements and then tried to select them with their class like this:

```
$("#map area.test-mapify").trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
```

Or even tried to loop through the elements and select them individually like this:

```
$.each([0, 1, 2], function(i, v) {
    $("#map area").eq(v).trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
});
```

And none of these solutions worked. In fact all of them would just be applied on the last element in the list which is the 3rd `area` element!

So the only workaround is this line that you have:

```
$(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').css("stroke", "#FFEB3B");
```

But it needs a little tweak. You have to add `opacity` in the `css` manually. So your code would be like this:

```
$(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2)').css("stroke", "#FFEB3B").css('opacity', '0.7');
```

Only apply this change in your code, and you are good to go...